# How to access Styx Browser & DuckDuckGo sessions/tabs on my Android & transferring them to my Linux PC, possibly ADB method, is root needed?

Tags: adb, browser, browser-tabs

I've tried every solution recommended. My smartphone is not rooted, it is an LG L355DL, LG K31 Rebel, Android version 10. I got many tabs on my browsers that I need to transfer & review. When I try to transfer each tab one by one using my phone, old social media sessions, Facebook links, etc, I open the tab, but they reset their URL to `facebook.com/login`, so I often lose where I was at completely when I try to click on them to share/transfer them to my PC or anywhere.

In other words, I have to open the tab again and refresh the URL, but in the process, the URL changes & sometimes resets itself to the domain, the common thing that happens when you're not re-logged into social media, etc. So I need a walk-through to access the session/tab files via ADB method, or something.

I do not have root access to my phone. I tried to do `adb pull /data/data/com.styxbrowser.browser/app_chrome/Default/*`, etc. I connected my PC to my phone via USB, but it doesn't work. Also, this forum post may help. Here are my terminal results/attempts: [www.rentry.co/cyube](http://www.rentry.co/cyube).

Lastly, there is interestingly another very different approach to accessing these files, it worked for my Android Kiwi browser. I connected my Android to my PC via USB, opened my Kiwi browser on my Android, turned on ADB on my phone, then went to `chrome://inspect/#devices` in my browser on my PC. I could see all tabs & could back them all up. It works like a charm. However, it doesn't work with Styx or Duckduckgo. Not sure why.

-Thanks!

Comment: Also posted on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1790095/356789

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Without root access, I'm afraid it will be difficult/impossible to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Andrew.